# Any way to put table filter and column toggle on same line side by side?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Any way to put the table filter and column toggle on the same line?  Seems there is no way to get a hold of the column toggle to put it where you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the filter input in a table with an empty cell for the column toggle:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="filterTable-input" data-type="search" />
        </td>
        <td id="columnsTD" style="width: 82px; padding-top: 4px;">

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then in code, move the column toggle button into the empty cell:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $(".ui-table-columntoggle-btn").appendTo($("#columnsTD"));;
});
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/fr8Yd/9/)**

**NOTE:** you do not have to use a table. You could use the jQM Grid or any other layout technique you like.